# Force page to reload a file if it's been changed

Tags: jquery, reload

I will use it for different purposes but here is a good example of what I want to build but I don't know how to:

I have a .txt document that occasionally updates and I want to make a page that load and show that .txt file and if it's been changed to force that page to reload. ONLY if it's been changed. 
I don't want to make it to reload every X seconds cause that will kill the server.

How can I do it? Ajax probably but I don't know what function or plugin to use.

EDIT: And another good example is a notification box that updates only if you have new notifications.

Comment: Can we get more information on your environment? This question very much depends on your current stack - for example: Is this content being served from an Apache server, or a node.js server, etc...?

Comment: Is your web page only showing the text file? 
I would make a call to the text file every "x" seconds and check if it is changed. And only reload if the file is changed. 

Is that out of question too? I am not sure.. but do you just not want to make the call to the text file every so often? or do you not want to reload the web page every so often?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having issues with the same thing. I have been trying something similar to this, but I think it's going to give issues with finding the ifModified heading on different file types?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">(function ajaxCall() {
console.log("working.")
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "path/to/file.txt",
  ifModified: true,
  success: function () {
 console.log("file was updated, reload");
 location.reload();
 setTimeout(ajaxCall, 5000);  // Check again in 5 seconds?
  }
});
})();
</script>
```